# How to store UTC Time in Model in Prisma (Node.js) using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, prisma, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to store MySQL not as a DateTime because it does not present the timezone that is using and might have problems with dates and validation.

Currently, I have it like this:

```
createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
```

and in the database is stored like this: `2023-07-22 18:25:41`

I want also to store also the UTC for example:

```
2023-07-23T08:38:27Z
```

Is there any way in prisma, or should I do it manually to store `createdAt` with the current timezone and put it as a value in the database under the `createdAt` column?

Because I want to make validations such as reset passwords where the time of the request is necessary to validate the token expiration time.